# multiview display for network video player in c# .NET

Tags: c#, video-player, multiview

I try to implement a video player which can display up to 16 video streams. I am getting streams from IP cameras and convert them to bitmap images using my "converter" object which is a class in my C++ dll. "converter" objects are created for each camera. 
I create 16 picture boxes on a windows form. Then, i set background images of 16 picture boxes with bitmaps received from "converter" objects. Then i refresh the picture boxes. But when i made such a design, API freezes for example; the buttons on the media player can not be clicked and i can't minimize the media player to the task bar. Buttons are not working. 
How can i display these 16 bitmap images on a windows form for every 40 ms(25fps) ? Is there another way from using panel or picture box?

Thank you for your advices.
Edit -> I add the code where i display image for each picture box. Every player object ( as many as IP cameras ) in .NET part has this thread to display RTP streams in picture boxes.

```
    private void DisplayFrameThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

                object message = mSyncDisplayFrameQueue.DequeueBlocking();
                RtpFrame frame = (RtpFrame)message;

                byte[] myRaw264 = Utils.GetH264Frame(frame);
                if (cudaDecoder.decodeH264Frame(myRaw264, myRaw264.Length))
                {
                    bool retVal = false;
                    //sw.Start();
                    byte[] bmpImageData = cudaDecoder.getDecodedBMPFrame(ref retVal);//~7 ms in Release mode in 1080p
                    // sw.Stop();
                    // Console.WriteLine("getDecodedBMPFrame in DisplayFrameThread" + " takes :" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
                    if (retVal)
                    {
                        //count++;
                        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bmpImageData), false, false);//0 ms..if validateImageData is made TRUE, then 3 ms.
                        picBox.BackgroundImage = bmp;
                        picBox.Refresh();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error in DisplayFrameThread -> " + ex.Message);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're much more likely to get a useful response from the community if you post the code you've written and point out exactly where you're having problems with it.

Comment: Use a task or background worker or something. You're probably locking up the main (UI) thread while doing your processing. Hard to say anything more specific without seeing a high level overview of your code.

Comment: i add the code where i display image for each picture box. Every player object ( as many as IP cameras ) in .NET part has this thread to display RTP streams in picture boxes